# Why is $y^{x-1}-1$ divisible by $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I wanted to know if there is a way to prove that $y^{x-1}-1$ is divisible by $x$. Where $x$ is a prime number and is not equal to $y$, and $y$ is any positive whole number besides $1$. For example, $y=2$ and $x=13$ so $2^{13-1}-1$ is simplified to $4095$ which is divisible by $13$.

Comment: Please see Fermat's Little Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem

Comment: It's true for any $y$ which is not divisible by $x$, including $y=1$ since $0$ is divisible by $x$.

Comment: It feels like there should be a "big list" of proofs of Fermat on this site, since there are so many lovely little proofs. I like a combinatorial one that prove $a^p-a$ is always divisible by $p$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that would be a great question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know some group theory this follows from the fact that the order a group element divides the group order: view $y$ as an element of the multiplicative group of units $(\mathbb{Z}/x\mathbb{Z})^*$. Since $x$ is prime, the latter has order $x-1$, whence $y^{x-1}\equiv 1$ mod $x$.

Comment: @Babak, sure if I can be of a help - mail me if you want, see my profile for the address.

Comment: Thanks for letting me do that.:-) Is n.s.hekster_at_nl.ibm.com Ok with you?

Comment: @Babak, yes, OK

Answer (score 1):

y^(x-1)-1=t
y^x-y=yt
By Fermat’s little theorem x|(y^x-y) and therefore x]yt
Since (x,y)=1, x|t. If y has the factor  x  , t is not divisible by x, which is obvious. I also must say , this is Fermat’s little theorem. 
P.Ranawaka